# How to make fade edges in image magic?

Tags: php, imagemagick, gdlib

I want to create faded edges image effect using imagemagic commands. Please help me for a command to make effect as like http://postimg.org/image/h51e4twyp/

Answer (score 1):

Start with [Doge](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/doge)

```
curl -o doge.jpg http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/581/296/c09.jpg
```

Next, blur the edges.

```
convert doge.jpg -alpha set -virtual-pixel transparent -channel A -morphology Distance Euclidean:1,20\! +channel doge.png
```

You will need to output it as a .png

[Imagemagick documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#soft_edges)

**Edit**: The above example is for ImageMagick v6.

For IMv7 try:

```
convert doge.jpg \( +clone -alpha extract -virtual-pixel black -gamma 2 +level 0,100 -white-threshold 99 -morphology Distance Euclidean:1,200! -sigmoidal-contrast 3,0% \) -compose CopyOpacity -composite doge_im7.png
```

Comment: When I run that on IM 7.0.0.0, the output image looks identical to the input image

Comment: This is a 4 year old answer. Back then it worked. There is even a matching example in the IMv6 docs.

Comment: @Petah how about now?