# How to fade images to blue with image magic?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, png, imagemagick-convert

Much like this question [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20209631/1908), im trying to achieve a fade but to a constant color rather than fade to transparent, how can the fade at all the edges, go to blue rather than to transparent?
I have tried the following:

```
convert doge.png -alpha set -virtual-pixel transparent -background blue  -channel A -morphology Distance Euclidean:1,20\! +channel _doge.png
convert doge.png -alpha set -virtual-pixel Blue  -channel A -morphology Distance Euclidean:1,20\! +channel _doge.png
```

unsuccessfully. I also considered  vignette [4](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/transform/#vignette) which it turns out produces very stretched ovals on my very rectangular images, making them unattractive, therefore i have a need to keep the fade to black rectangular, if i can use this fade to produce a fade to black it would suffice.

with the first command i get this, before and after:
[image: Before], [image: After]
The second command errs out with this error:

```
convert: unrecognized virtual pixel method `Blue' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3177.
```

Comment: A before and after image would help.

Comment: @MarkSetchell there you go

Comment: I thought you wanted to fade to blue?

Comment: yes, there lies the problem, its not fading to blue, but to transparent! how do i make image magic fade to a color rather than to transparent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your doing the morphology on the Alpha channel, but what about just the Red & Green channels.

```
 convert doge.png -alpha set -virtual-pixel transparent -background blue \
         -channel RG -morphology Distance Euclidean:1,20\! +channel _doge.png
```

[image: doge]

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by the following in Imagemagick 6. I create a black image and blur the edges linearly rather than by a gaussian blur. Then I use that as a mask to blend the image with a blue image to make the results.

```
convert doge.png \
\( -clone 0 -fill blue -colorize 100 \) \
\( -clone 0 -fill black -colorize 100 -virtual-pixel white -blur 100x65000 \) \
-compose over -composite \
result.png
```

[image]

You can also use a gaussian-like blur as follows:

```
convert doge.png \
\( -clone 0 -fill blue -colorize 100 \) \
\( -clone 0 -fill black -colorize 100 -virtual-pixel white -blur 0x50 \) \
-compose over -composite \
result2.png
```

[image]

Here is a smaller blur distance:

```
convert doge.png \
\( -clone 0 -fill blue -colorize 100 \) \
\( -clone 0 -fill black -colorize 100 -virtual-pixel white -blur 20x65000 \) \
-compose over -composite \
result3.png
```

[image]

If you want it more deep blue, then you can control that with the -level operator:

```
convert doge.png \
\( -clone 0 -fill blue -colorize 100 \) \
\( -clone 0 -fill black -colorize 100 -virtual-pixel white -blur 20x65000 -level 0x50% \) \
-compose over -composite \
result4.png
```

[image]

For Imagemagick 7, use magick rather than convert.

Answer (score 2):

A slight variation to emcconville's excellent Imagemagick answer is to keep the transparency and just flatten against blue.

```
convert doge.png \
-alpha set -virtual-pixel transparent -channel A -morphology Distance Euclidean:1,20\! +channel  \
-background blue -compose over -flatten \
result.png
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Several good answers have been provided above, but here's a slightly different approach. Read the input image, clone it, colorize it black, shave it some and add a blue border, make the black transparent, blur the blue border, and composite that over the original input. A command might look something like this...

```
convert input.png -bordercolor blue -fill black \
   \( +clone -colorize 100 -shave 10 -border 10 \
   -transparent black -blur 0x10 \) -composite result.png
```